# Load Textbox from database using selected item changed combobox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce

I have an exception when I tried to load form contains two Combobox and two textbox 
I load Combobox items from the database , I try to load data from table Bureau and filling them on the two textbox
Pictures :
[The Exception that I get]

[image]

[The form that I have]

[image]

```
public partial class Modifier : Form
{

    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

    public SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\Program Files\projetpfe\Inventaire.sdf");

    public SqlCeDataAdapter da, da2;
    public SqlCeCommand cmd, cmd2;
    public SqlCeDataReader dr,dr2;
    public Modifier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select Code_locale from Bureau", conn);
        this.da2 = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select DISTINCT Adresse from Bureau ", conn); 
        this.cmd = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from Bureau where Code_locale='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'", conn);

        conn.Open();

    }

    private void Modifier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.ds.Tables.Clear();
        this.da.Fill(this.ds, "Bureau");
        comboBox1.DataSource = this.ds.Tables["Bureau"];
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Code_locale";
        this.ds2.Tables.Clear();
        this.da2.Fill(this.ds2, "Bureau");
        comboBox2.DataSource = this.ds2.Tables["Bureau"];
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Adresse";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem is in the cmd.executereader() and cmd (SqlCecommand) is select * from bureau where code_locale='" + combobox1.SelectedValue +"'", conn) not combobox2.selectedvalue and also you should see the picture that conatains the form

Comment: I shouldn't see anything.. you should debug your code.. and what you should do is learn how to construct a Parameterized Query.. what is the Selected Value when you are stepping through the code.. perhaps you should be choosing the Text of the combobox.. good luck

Comment: I dont know how to get the selected value from combobox , that is my whole problem that gives exception , how can i get the selected item from combobox , i want when i selected item from combobox items the textbox get values from the table Bureau depending on the selected, Any solution?

Comment: if you do not know, then do a simple google search on `C# getting Selected Value from ComboBox` there are seriously `1000's` of working examples

Comment: `cmd = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from Bureau where Code_locale= '" + comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + "'", conn);

        
            //more code
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                textBox1.Text = dr.GetString(1).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString();
            }
        }`  i changed my code and i changed the type of value of column Code_locale as nvarchar , so now it should anything no error and no data in the textbox??

Comment: learn how to construct parameterized query's this will save you a lot of headaches in regards to double quote single quote wrapping.

Comment: I solved My problem , i use an the event combobox selected changed and it solve my issue ;)

Comment: 4 days later.... good job..

Comment: thanks , please mark my comment as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved My problem , i used the event combobox selected changed and i copy all code to the combobox selected changed event and it solve my issue, the textbox show datareader when i selecte a combobox item**